# How did Solo catch Beckett?

Tags: star-wars, han-solo, solo-a-star-wars-story

At the end of *Solo: A Star Wars Story*, Tobias Beckett leaves with Chewbacca held at gunpoint and carrying across the sandy beach two large, heavy cases of hyperfuel.

The remaining characters are left to fight and converse before Solo can pursue Beckett and Chewie. In the next scene, we see him ahead of and waiting for them.

How could this be? Were we shown some kind of transport vehicle in the background? Did he run a large arc around the slow-moving pair? Why not run up behind them?

Comment: I'd like an aswer in the movie, but I'm afraid it's just a "rule of cool" kind of thing.

Comment: Its easy to catch Beckette.  First, you set a trap for Castle.   Then, you use him as bait to lure Beckette into your trap.   Oh.  Wait.  Wrong story.

Comment: Marauder's speeders.

Comment: @JRE - I know what you mean - I saw this and thought,"Huh, sounds like Sam leapt *way* outside his lifetime - and galaxy!"

Comment: This seems to run in the family as his son Kylo Ren does the same in The Force Awakens - Finn and Rey have a head start and then the are blocked by Kylo, who has teleported in front of them on Starkiller base.

Answer (score 13):

The only thing Han says in reference to the encounter is that he "got there as fast as he could", so there's not much in the film to give us a clue as to how. But it's not that implausible a situation.

The fight on the ship by those left behind lasted no more than a few minutes at most, plus another couple minutes to for Qi'ra and Han to part ways. That means Beckett had only a few minutes head start at best, and at walking pace. Catching up would have been fairly easy even without transport.

As to why he chose to show up in front instead of behind, at the very least it means he can set the terms of engagement. If coming from behind, he's going to have to work with whatever terrain they're in by the time Beckett hears him coming up, which could potentially be disadvantageous. If Beckett is crossing a ridge and Han is out in the open for example, Beckett could take cover and Han would be in trouble. But by moving ahead and finding a place of his choosing to have the confrontation, he at least has that working in his favor (or at least not disadvantage).

As to why he didn't take cover and ambush, it's pretty clear he wasn't keen on shooting someone he once looked up to and considered a mentor/friend, and wanted to talk him down first. When it was clear that Beckett's intentions were still malicious, Han took the shot.

Comment: Also, since he was working with those marauders, he could've been dropped off up ahead by one of them. Their speeder things were small(ish) and quiet(ish).

Comment: Chewbacca might also have been slowed down by the heavy cases Beckett made him carry.

Answer (score 6):

Chewbacca was "burdened" and Han Solo ran at a faster pace along a more direct route over rough ground.

> He wasn’t what you could call “lucky” unless you counted that he was
> still alive after every plan he’d ever formed had gone wrong. But this
> one, strangely enough, worked. A dash down the beach toward the port,
> climbing a rocky hill to get to the dunes, and waiting patiently for
> them to come along at Chewbacca’s burdened, ponderous gait.
>
> <sub><sup>[Solo: A Star Wars Story: Expanded Edition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Solo:_A_Star_Wars_Story:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>